# How to use WiX to delete a font

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am creating an installer that also needs to delete the Arial font (I am told Arial will be recreated from a cache if it gets deleted, and that's exactly what I want). Is there a way that I can do this in WiX or will I need to write a custom action?

**Update:** Users of my installer will 90% of the time have a hacked version of Arial which conflicts with the font fall back mechanism of Web Browsers. It is good to confirm that Arial will be recreated if I deleted it, as technically I can not redistribute an updated Arial font without permission.

**Update 2:** I was able to delete it, however inside the Fonts folder the Arial font is still there but looks orphaned. That is I can see it, but if I doulbe click it it says font is of incorrect format.

Comment: I think you shouldn't automatically delete a font, that is standard on system, even if it will be automatically recreated. It's like deleting something from system32, that is delivered with the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could work, even if i did not recommend it in my comment:

```
   <Directory Id="FontsFolder">
      <RemoveFile Id="RemoveArial" On="install" Name="Arial.ttf"/>
   </Directory>
```

Comment: Don't forget ariali.ttf, arialbd.ttf and arialbi.ttf.